# Mount exFAT on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, ntfs, sd-card, exfat

I have a Lenovo Carbon X1 with a 128SSD. I'm dual booting Win7 (need it for a couple of apps that don't run on Win 8) and Win8, so once the OS and apps are on the drive there's not much room for data.

The X1 is an ultrabook, so there are no bays available for extra storage. As such I'm using a 256GB SD card (Lexar 400x) for my data. I also use SkyDrive to keep my data synced to the cloud.

My plan was to format the SD as NTFS so I can use a mount-point to set the Skydrive folder to the SD card (by default, you can't use removable storage - dunno why!) However, when I format as NTFS the write speed is atrocious (didn't check the kbps, but it took over an hour to copy 9MB!) When I reformat at exFAT, the SD write speed is fine.

So, what do I do? Can I get the NTFS file system performant by tweaking the allocation blocks, or using some "trick" (diskpart maybe?) to format it properly? Alternatively, can I set up the exFAT partition with a mount-point from Windows?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  There is software that will extend support to exFAT to WIndows.

Comment: 2 Questions: 1. Can I make NTFS perform as fast as exFat and 2. Can I set a mount-point to an exFat partition

Comment: SDXC cards always come pre-formatted as exFAT. Perhaps instead of formatting the card itself as NTFS, you can see whether an NTFS VHD on the card (that you can attach via Disk Management) performs better?

Comment: Three things to note: 
1) using a journaling filesystem would decrease your SD Card lifetime.
2) one hour to copy 9MB seems like your card is too slow, seek for a class 10 card, the ones suitable for 4k video recording.
3) be aware of security issues since your data won't be encrypted.